# Return my Helvetica Neue to default (Windows 10)

Tags: firefox, fonts

For a design project, I installed the font from [this website](https://freefontsfamily.com/helvetica-neue-font-free/)

And now some websites are very hard to read:

[image: example]

[image]

When I try to delete it in Windows Settings, I can't because it's "In use" even when all programs are closed.

Is there a way to go back to the default behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I try to delete it in Windows Settings, I can't because it's "In
> use" even when all programs are closed.

**(A) Open MSCONFIG** (Admin Tools) and in the Boot tab, set for minimal boot.  Restart and remove the Font.

OR

**(B) Restart in Safe Mode** (often F8 on restart but that may depend open your computer) and then remove the Font.

The objective is to not have apps starting that use the Font.

Comment: Will removing it cause those sites to just not have text? Or will Windows put the default font back in somehow?

Comment: If you remove the Font, then yes, after restart it should go back to normal.

Comment: That worked! Thank you!